# How to limit/change available table style options on the Design tab

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, templates

I'm setting up a format that will be used by many people in different departments.  I don't want each to pick a different table style from the 140 or so built-in styles.  I want them to pick one of my two options. How can I eliminate the built-in styles from appearing in the `Table Tools`>`Design` drop-down list?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to delete the Styles in the Folder where they are located.

There's no way of locking built-in styles to my knowledge.

Comment: I'm unclear where the folder is that contains the table styles. They are listed in the 'Manage Styles' window.  I recognize that they cannot be deleted, but can they be made to not show up?

Comment: If it is System Protected, there are a few free scripts or shells that allow you take over the folder. Taking over a Folder can be done with your command processor.                                           There are few places where software can place their folders like in TEMP, USERS, APPS or somewhere in the SYSTEM Folder.                  You could try to make the Custom Template show first through some options. If you really want to get rid of the templates, you could make a custom install or not load the resources through some hacks if it is an important component. Give the Software name

Answer (score 0):

In trying to achieve the same result, I accidentally stumbled onto a solution that works a treat (after wasting hours on this challenge and concluding that it's impossible to hide these annoyances).

This macro has two functions - the first disables visibility of **all** styles, including table styles; the second enables visibility only for those styles listed. It is commented, but please note that the Visibility property seems to work completely counterintuitively in this context, i.e. on/true = **not** visible and off/false = visible. Go figure.

You'll also see that my list of styles to display includes both inbuilt and custom styles - this is where you would add your table styles.

Unfortunately, I'm one of these copy / adapt / paste wannabe-coders, so I probably can't offer any further assistance if this doesn't do it for you. (But my own attempts to create a default table style exactly as I want for my template it have been completely crushed by Word 2010 - so if you've succeeded, I'd be interested to learn how you did it!).

hope this helps

**neil**

Anyhow... on with the code:

```
Sub RehideStyles()
'
'
'
Dim oSty As Style
Dim oArray As Variant
Dim n As Long


'Start deselecting all - NOTE: Visibility = true means NOT VISIBLE!
With ActiveDocument
For Each oSty In .Styles
.Styles(oSty.NameLocal).Visibility = True
Next oSty
'Display the desired styles - include the names in oArray
oArray = Array(wdStyleBodyText, wdStyleHeading1, wdStyleHeading2, wdStyleHeading3, wdStyleHeading4, wdStyleHeading5, wdStyleHeading6, wdStyleHeading7, wdStyleHeading8, wdStyleHeading9, "Table Text", "List Bullet", "List Number", "WP")
For n = LBound(oArray) To UBound(oArray)
.Styles(oArray(n)).Visibility = False
Next n
End With

End Sub
```